# signature image path can't save into database

Tags: php, mysql, digital-signature

I create the Signature Pad using https://laratutorials.com/signature-pad-php-mysql-jquery/.
The problem is when I click submit, the signature image path can't save into database.

Here is the code for upload.php

```
<?php
include_once '../db_connect.php';

$folderPath = "upload/";

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $_POST['signed']);
    
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
  
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
  
$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
  
$file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '.'.$image_type;
$sql="INSERT INTO works (sign) VALUES ('$file') WHERE id=1";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  
file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
echo "Signature Uploaded Successfully.";
?>
```

Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

sign field in mysql database change varchar to **text field** it can store in database

Comment: try already, still cannot

Comment: signature it not save database but you can save signature image path save in database after can get fetch path and get that signature file from file storage

Comment: Yes, I need the image path save in database, but now can't work

Comment: you need upload signature in path .

Comment: <?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';

$folderPath = "upload/";
  
$file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '.jpg';

$sql="INSERT INTO works (sign) VALUES ('$file')";

mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  
echo "Signature Uploaded Successfully.";
?>

Comment: I using and try still cannot work

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dBdG.png)
solved it. please make sure your query and table in another field is not null

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL statement

`$sql="INSERT INTO works (sign) VALUES ('$file') WHERE id=1";`

you don't need `WHERE id=1`, it  is actually an error.
you should check the return value of mysqli_query()